# How to determine if you've discovered a new identity for a special function

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, sequences-and-series, special-functions, journals

Often times, we consult resources, like Abramowitz and Stegun's  Handbook of Mathematical Functions [https://www.math.ubc.ca/~cbm/aands/](https://www.math.ubc.ca/%7Ecbm/aands/), NIST's database on special functions https://www.nist.gov/programs-projects/special-functions, or Mathematica to find identities which aid us with some kind of computation.

However, what if we want to know if we have found a new identity, want to systematically check against the above resources, and want to add to the library in the case the identity is new? Also, are there journals which, even today, still consider mathematical effort toward discovering identities of classical functions?

Comment: `Sum[Binomial[2j,j](Cos[x]/2)^(2j),{j,0,\[Infinity]}]` in Mathematica gives `1/Sqrt[Sin[x]^2]`

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Thanks! I've removed this part of the question so that more important (soft) question remains.

Comment: If you really discovered a new identity, just contact the editors of NIST, and ask for inclusion.

Comment: By the way, $\sum_{j=0}^\infty {2j \choose j} x^j = (1-4x)^{-1/2}$ is well known and your result follows.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

***Q:*** Are there journals which would publish identities of classical functions?

***A:***  Elsevier's *Applied Mathematics and Computation* has published quite a number of papers in that category, see this [search listing](https://www.sciencedirect.com/search?qs=identities&pub=Applied%20Mathematics%20and%20Computation&cid=271588).

It is ranked as a Q1 journal, open access is optional.

Comment: In case anyone is wondering, "Q1 journal" appears to means this has a top quartile rank, in somebody's ranking.

Comment: some of us face the complication when choosing a publication venue that only Q1 journals count for things like promotion or tenure, so this might be relevant data; the full list in mathematics is [here](https://www.scimagojr.com/journalrank.php?area=2600)